# Is there a java function for swapping the values of two variables?

Tags: java, object

swapping the values of two variables in the same  Class;
for  example  exchange `<String stra ; String strb;>`

or some  other Object,collections,etc;

Is there a java function ?

In PHP I find a function list() to exchange two variables .so I asked in java.Thinks for your suggestion

Comment: Not as far as I know.  Normally you just code that yourself, takes about three lines of code.

Comment: Not actually a very common requirement in code, swapping variables.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such function and it is impossible to create it.
Java pass parameters by value.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not (yet) has support for that. The Bytecode supports such a statement.

There is a language who creates the Bytecode you are searching for: **Jasmin** (without tailing `e`). Who has the statement:

```
pop
iconst_1
swap
```

But not (yet) in plain java.

Comment: I'd be disappointed if they wasted time on such a trivial enhancement.

Comment: @StephenC http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/ ? Never heard of it? It creates bytecode more low-level.

Comment: Sure I have heard of it.   But I don't see how that sequence of bytecodes swaps two **variables**.  How does it do that?

Comment: @StephenC Its not bytecode, its jasmin and only the last command does the swap. It opcode `5f` working with two variables on stack, maybe different machine-code, guess assembler `cpne` `cmp` and `cpy` on i64 - dont hit me if I am wrong about the machine-code.

Comment: Found a table on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings its 4th last.

Answer (score -1):

There are lot of way to swap the members within a class.

for example consider a class Room.

```
class Room{
int roomNo;
Room(int num){this.roomNo=num;}
}

class Main{

public static void exchMem(Room r1,Room r2)
{
int swap = r1.roomNo;
r1.roomNo = r2.roomNo;
r2.roomNo=swap;
}
public static void main(String[] params){

Room r1 = new Room(201);
Room r2 = new Room(301);

 exchMem(r1, r2);
    System.out.println("r1.no = " + r1.no);
    System.out.println("r2.no = " + r2.no);

}
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't swap values of variables, but some properties of that values.